# change a single row into columns in a file

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk

I have a file with data in this format (only one row)

```
1 2 3 5 7 9
```

I want to change this to

```
1
2
3
5
7
9
```

**EDIT:**

The sample input has 6 numbers. But actual data can have 1000s of numbers.

I can copy the file into an excel and do a transpose. But is it possible to do this using `awk` or `sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use `sed` for this:

```
echo 1 2 3 5 7 9 | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

Or if you have it all in one file:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' < filename
```

Comment: Thanks. But the number of elements are not just 6 elements. There can be 1000s of them

Comment: Not all version of sed have the -r flag.

Comment: @JoeNahmias: I did not downvote. Your second version worked for me

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky: true. as it turns out, it's not necessary for the solution, so i will remove it

Comment: @JoeNahmias sed has a much under used translate command `y/ /\n/`

Answer (score 4):

```
kent$ (master|✔) echo "1 2 3 5 7 9"|tr ' ' '\n'
1
2
3
5
7
9
```

Comment: Since the data is in a file, it would be cat fileName | tr ' ' '\n'.

Comment: Perhaps `cat bla.txt | tr " " "\n" | cat > bla.txt`

Answer (score 3):

using xargs.

```
echo 1 2 3 5 7 9  |xargs -n1
```

Or if you have it all in one file:

```
xargs -n1 < file
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a test file of 1M numbers with

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {printf "%d ", i} }' > t.txt
```

Results:

```
$ time tr ' ' '\n' <t.txt | tail -n 2
999998
999999
real    0m0.018s
$ time sed 's/ /\n/g' t.txt | tail -n 2
999998
999999
real    0m0.223s
$ time awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i}' t.txt | tail -n 2
999998
999999
real    0m0.400s
```

Thus `tr` is the fastest method.

Answer (score 1):

..

```
awk 1 RS='[[:space:]]+' file
```

Comment: I guess this only works for `gnu awk` due to the `RS`

Comment: @Jotne Thanks, I was not aware of that.

Comment: As far as I know, only `gnu awk` support more than one character as record selector `RS`.  Taken from `gnu awk` manual: `When using gawk, the value of RS is not limited to a one-character string.`

Comment: You can make it more portable by manipulating `OFS`, e.g. `awk '$1=$1' OFS='\n'`.

Comment: @Thor Thanks, good idea! I wonder why this also works if there is more than a single line in the file. That is, why does it not output the ORS (which is also a new line)?

Comment: @Jotne: `mawk` also has this feature.

Comment: @Thor If I do `echo -e "1 2\n\n\n3" | awk '$1=$1' OFS='\n'` I do not get any empty lines. If it was outputting the ORS, I should get two empty lines?

Comment: @Thor  All I do know is that many `awk` does not have it, so I write a note about it while I do use function that not all `awk` has. It will help user to understand why it does not work :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Ah I see what you mean now. This is because of `$1=$1` being empty, the more correct way would be to use: `{$1=$1}1` or perhaps: `!NF || $1=$1`.

Comment: @Thor Yes I do see the difference, but I do not understand it :)

Comment: @Thor Is it because `$1=$1` evaluates to false if there is no fields?